# Numpy modify ndarray diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way in numpy to get a reference to the array diagonal?
I want my array diagonal to be divided by a certain factor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If `X` is your array and `c` is the factor,

```
X[np.diag_indices_from(X)] /= c
```

See [`diag_indices_from`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices_from.html#numpy.diag_indices_from) in the Numpy manual.

Answer (score 21):

A quick way to access the diagonal of a square `(n,n)` numpy array is with `arr.flat[::n+1]`:

```
n = 1000
c = 20
a = np.random.rand(n,n)

a[np.diag_indices_from(a)] /= c # 119 microseconds
a.flat[::n+1] /= c # 25.3 microseconds
```

Answer (score 17):

The `np.fill_diagonal` function is quite fast:

```
np.fill_diagonal(a, a.diagonal() / c)
```

where `a` is your array and `c` is your factor. On my machine, this method was as fast as @kwgoodman's `a.flat[::n+1] /= c` method, and in my opinion a bit clearer (but not as slick).

Answer (score 9):

## Comparing the above 3 methods:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

n = 1000
c = 20
a = np.random.rand(n,n)
a1 = a.copy()
a2 = a.copy()
a3 = a.copy()

t1 = np.zeros(1000)
t2 = np.zeros(1000)
t3 = np.zeros(1000)

for i in range(1000):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    a1[np.diag_indices_from(a1)] /= c 
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    t1[i] = start-stop

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    a2.flat[::n+1] /= c
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    t2[i] = start-stop

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    np.fill_diagonal(a3,a3.diagonal() / c)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    t3[i] = start-stop

print([t1.mean(), t1.std()])
print([t2.mean(), t2.std()])
print([t3.mean(), t3.std()])

[-4.5693619907979154e-05, 9.3142851395411316e-06]
[-2.338075107036275e-05, 6.7119609571872443e-06]
[-2.3731951987429056e-05, 8.0455946813059586e-06]
```

So you can see that the `np.flat` method is the fastest but marginally. When I ran this for a few more times there were times when the `fill_diagonal` method was slightly faster. But readability wise its probably worth using the fill_diagonal method.