# How to change the values of the diagonal of a matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to set the diagonal of some `numpy` matrix to an arbitrary 1D array.

For example, if:

```
mat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
diag = np.array([5,6])
```

then:

```
>>> set_diagonal(mat, diag)
>>> mat
... array([[5,2],
           [3,6]])
```

I *could* create a diagonal matrix from the `diag` variable, `diag_fill` the `mat` matrix to `0` and add the results.  However, this seems to use a bunch of unnecessary resources if I'm trying to alter the diagonal in place.

How do I set the diagonal of a matrix in `numpy`?

Note: this is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958577/changing-the-values-of-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix-in-numpy), as they want to set the diagonal to a *constant*.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [numpy.fill_diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html)

According to the docs:

> numpy.fill_diagonal(a, val, wrap=False) .
>   Fill the main diagonal of the given array of any dimensionality.

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

np.fill_diagonal(mat, [5,6])
print(mat)
#[[5 2]
# [3 6]]
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
diag = np.array([5,6])
np.fill_diagonal(mat, diag)
print(mat)
#[[5 2]
# [3 6]]
```

Comment: huh.  "val : scalar"... This seems to suggest that this would not work... and yet it does.  So the `val` argument need not be a scalar.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't read that fine print! But somehow it works lol! If this helped you, could you please mark my answer as accepted @Scott :)

Comment: You can see how it works in the [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L749-L861) - it ends up just assigning `val` to a slice of the array, so that works if `val` is a 1d array of the right size. Would be nice if it were documented behaviour though!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass that 1d array to `fill_diagonal`.

```
np.fill_diagonal(mat, [5,6])
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers using `fill_diagonal` are much more elegant and computationally efficient, but you can also access the diagonal indices and then change them:

```
mat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
diag = np.array([5,6])

row, col = np.diag_indices(mat.shape[0])

mat[row, col] = diag
```

See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261325/fill-matrix-diagonal-with-different-values-for-each-python-numpy) for more info: